# How to make table responsive and attractive using bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, html

I have to show table in a responsive and attractive manner using bootstrap. Currently, it is looking like a simple table and I want it to be eye catching using bootstrap.

I have used simple html and nothing else and want to make it look attractive.

here is my code-

```
        var table = $("<table>");
        table.append($("<tr><th>column1</th><th>column2</th></tr>"));

        for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        var row = $('<tr ><td>' + 'data' + '</td><td>' + 'data' + '</td> 
        </tr>');


        table.append(row);
          }
        $("#table").html(table);
```

div content-

```
        <div id="table">
        </div>
```

css-

```
        #table {
        margin-top: 20px;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 500px;
        }

        #table th {
        border: 1px solid black;
        text-align: left;
        }
```

I am using simple css and html and want to use bootstrap to make my table look attractive and responsive.

Comment: You are not using bootstrap in your code. Check how to include bootstrap

Answer (score 2):

If you are using **Bootstrap**, there is no need to create your own responsive class, because there is already a *responsive* class available for table elements:

```
<table class="table responsive">
...
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Bootstrap use

```
<table class="table-responsive">

</table>
```

or other wise use css

```
    #table{
    width:100%;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}
table th, td {
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: left;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

table tr:hover {background-color:#f5f5f5;}
```

Comment: how to add table class through my code? can you please tell?

Comment: @AhbaySingh it goes in your CSS file, just like all other CSS

Answer (score 0):

You can enhance the look and responsiveness of your table using Bootstrap classes. Here's an example of how you can modify your code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <title>Responsive and Attractive Table</title>
  <style>
    /* Your custom CSS goes here */
    #table {
      margin-top: 20px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div id="table" class="table-responsive">
      <!-- Bootstrap table classes added -->
      <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <!-- Your table rows go here -->
          <tr>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>Data</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>Data</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

In this example, I've added Bootstrap classes to your table, making it responsive and visually appealing. The table-responsive class ensures that the table is responsive on smaller screens, and table-bordered and table-striped add styling to the table. You can customize the styles further based on your preferences by adjusting the Bootstrap classes and adding your own custom CSS.

Check this blog for a better understanding: https://ninjatables.com/bootstrap-table/